# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver exception

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I am seeing some weird behavior when attempting to access a database using JDBC drivers. Here's the code fragment:

```
LOGGER.debug("driver is " + driver);
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    LOGGER.debug("got driver");
} catch (Throwable t) {
    LOGGER.debug("throwable getting driver " + driver);
    t.printStackTrace(System.out);
    throw t;
}
```

When I run this, here's what I see in the stack trace.

```
08:20:00.417 [main] DEBUG - driver is com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
08:20:00.604 [main] DEBUG - throwable getting driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:555)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:547)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:449)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:426)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(Unknown Source)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        ... my code
```

So I can see that the driver name that I am trying to get is com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver which is correct, but for some reason, the DriverManager is looking for oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.

What is going on? This code has been working well for years, and the only other relevant information I can think of is that I have recently upgraded the JDK on this machine to Open JDK 11.

```
>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Probably, you don't have the respective jar file in your classpath. Have you checked the same?

Comment: Do you have a deeper stacktrace, maybe with an exception cause?

Comment: You don't need this code. It has been unnecessary since 2007. Just remove it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I removed my use of Class.forName() and checked that all of the relevant JDBC library JAR files were Type 4 (ie contained the META-INF\services\java.sql.Driver file). However, I still see the same problem: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver when the application attempts to use the com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver

Comment: I can avoid this error by removing the Oracle JDBC library JAR from the classpath, but this won't solve my problem in Production when the application needs to connect to both Oracle and Sybase databases.

Comment: @user304582 did you got the solution, i'm facing the same issue. when i run it in eclipse it is able to make connection but when i create war and run war in server then getting same error

Comment: I am afraid that I don't remember how I resolved this! You can see below that I investigated a couple of solutions, but then moved on to other things. Sorry not to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it seems to be a class loading problem in combination with automatic driver loading.

When you explicitly use `Class.forName` to load a JDBC driver, the driver should register itself with `java.sql.DriverManager`.

Looking at the stack trace, specifically:

> ```
>     at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:426)
>     at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<init>(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> ```

The Sybase driver incorrectly checks currently registered drivers (using `DriverManager.getDrivers`) before (?) registering itself. And even worse, it does this from the driver constructor instead of a static initializer, which could potentially lead to a driver loading deadlock. A proper behaving driver should call `DriverManager.registerDriver` from a static initializer as specified in JDBC 4.3 section 9.2:

> JDBC drivers must implement the `Driver` interface, and the
>   implementation must contain a static initializer that will be called
>   when the driver is loaded. This initializer registers a new instance
>   of itself with the `DriverManager`, as shown in CODE EXAMPLE 9-1.
>
> ```
> public class AcmeJdbcDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
>     static {
>         java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new AcmeJdbcDriver());
>     }
>     ... 
> }
> ```
>
> CODE EXAMPLE 9-1 Example static initializer for a driver implementing `java.sql.Driver`
>
> When a `Driver` implementation is loaded, the static initializer will
>   automatically register an instance of the driver.

Because `DriverManager.getDrivers` is called, it will automatically load drivers on the classpath in `META-INF/service/java.sql.Driver` files (and those in the system property `jdbc.drivers`).

It looks like the Oracle JDBC driver was discovered **and** loaded this way, but then a check if the driver is available in the current class loader in `isDriverAllowed` fails with a `NoClassDefFoundError` (the check catches exceptions, but not errors, and maybe it should).

As a workaround, you should either remove the Oracle JDBC driver from your class path, or find out why it is not available in the current class loader.

As further diagnosis, try to call `DriverManager.getDrivers()`, `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.Driver`) or even `new oracle.jdbc.Driver()` in your code and see what happens.

You may also want to check the version of your Sybase driver, and if there is a newer version that doesn't do this check, although that may simply cause the error to occur elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I haven't yet solved the problem, but this is very helpful. I added DriverManager.getDrivers(); and then reran the code. I should add here that my classpath includes multiple JAR files that contain JDBC drivers. One of these JAR files is ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar. If this is included in the classpath, then the application throws an error at DriverManager.getDrivers() line. If I remove this JAR file from the classpath, then I can see the list of other JDBC drivers as expected. Replacing with ojdbc7.jar did not help.

I'm going to try to see if upgrading the Sybase driver helps here...

Comment: @user304582 As you are using Java 11 (or at least 9 or higher), you may want to try even newer versions of the Oracle JDBC driver (eg 18.3). I don't know the exact context of the error, so it is hard to provide more specific help though. It might be helpful to post the full exception stacktrace, and describe more about your application (eg is it a simple application, or is it a Java EE app, or ..., how are the dependencies arranged, etc). If you can reduce it to the bare minimum by creating a [mcve], that could also help.

Answer (score 1):

this is syabse jdbc driver, which is causing issues. you can try to re-order(put oracle dependency prior/much prior to sybase) sybase and ojdbc8 jar dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
            <version>7.07-27082</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: did this resolved issue for you, because i tried, but still getting error. one observation is that if i keep ojdbc below jconnect, i'm getting error in application start only

Answer (score 0):

So I did some further investigation as follows. I wrote a minimal complete example:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestDrivers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Enumeration<Driver> driverEnumeration = DriverManager.getDrivers();
            while (driverEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                Driver driver = driverEnumeration.nextElement();
                System.out.println("driver is " + driver.getClass().getName());
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("throwable getting drivers");
            t.printStackTrace(System.out);
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

I then ran this example with four different classpaths with the following results:

1. No driver JAR files: success, no drivers listed
2. Driver JAR files: jconn4.jar;jtds-1.3.1.jar;ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar: failure with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
3. Driver JAR files: jtds-1.3.1.jar;ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar: success with jTDS and Oracle drivers listed
4. Driver JAR files: jconn4.jar;jtds-1.3.1.jar: success with jTDS and Sybase drivers listed

So there is some weird interaction going on if both Oracle and Sybase JDBC drivers are present. I also tried the Oracle ojdbc7.jar and ojdbc8.jar files with essentially the same results. Here's the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:555)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:547)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:449)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:426)
        at com.javamarket.drivers.TestDrivers.main(TestDrivers.java:10)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:555)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:547)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:449)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:426)
        at com.javamarket.drivers.TestDrivers.main(TestDrivers.java:10)
```

Finally, I tried this on a different machine running JDK 8 and all four classpath variations run successfully.

Comment: Have you also tried with a newer version of the Oracle JDBC driver (eg 18.3)? Also, which version of the Sybase driver is this?

Comment: Also, what is the logging if you run this with `java -Xlog:class*=debug`